# How to sort an array of object properties? or turn object properties upside down

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

Hey guys kind of ran into a problem and would like some help.... I am having trouble trying to replicate this array of objects...

```
   {
  "recipe_id" : 1,
  "recipe_name": "Spaghetti Bolognese",
  "created_at": "2021-01-01 08:23:19.120",
  "steps": [
    {
      "step_id": 11,
      "step_number": 1,
      "step_instructions": "Put a large saucepan on a medium heat",
      "ingredients": []
    },
    {
      "step_id": 12,
      "step_number": 2,
      "step_instructions": "Add 1 tbsp olive oil",
      "ingredients": [
        { "ingredient_id": 27, "ingredient_name": "olive oil", "quantity": 0.014 }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

The result that I am getting is something like this

```
{
    "created_at": "2021-01-03 09:08:19.150",
    "recipe_id": 2,
    "recipe_name": "chicken nuggets",
    "steps": [
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 7,
            "step_instructions": "Go to backyard",
            "step_number": 1
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 8,
            "step_instructions": "find a chicken",
            "step_number": 2
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 9,
            "step_instructions": "take its nuggets",
            "step_number": 3
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 10,
            "step_instructions": "season nuggets with spices",
            "step_number": 4
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 10,
            "step_instructions": "season nuggets with spices",
            "step_number": 4
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [],
            "step_id": 11,
            "step_instructions": "cook for 30 minute till done",
            "step_number": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

The way I am doing this is like this :

```
async function getRecipeById(recipeId){

  const recipe = await db('recipes as r')
    .join('steps as s','s.recipe_id','r.recipe_id')
    .leftJoin('step_ingredients as si', 'si.recipe_steps_id', 's.recipe_steps_id')
    .leftJoin('ingredients as i', 'i.ingredient_id', 'si.ingredient_id')
    .select('r.*','s.recipe_steps_id','s.recipe_steps_number','s.recipe_step_instructions','i.ingredient_id','i.ingredient_name','si.step_ingredient_quantity')
    .where('r.recipe_id',recipeId)


  const result = {
    recipe_id: recipe[0].recipe_id,
    recipe_name: recipe[0].recipe_name,
    created_at: recipe[0].createdAt,
    steps: []
  }

  let ingredients = []

  recipe.forEach(step => {

    if(step.recipe_steps_id){
      result.steps.push({
        step_id: step.recipe_steps_id,
        step_number: step.recipe_steps_number,
        step_instructions: step.recipe_step_instructions,
        ingredients: ingredients
      })
    }

  });

  return result
```

When I create a way to implement the ingredient into my work it ends up going upside down pretty much..

```
    "created_at": "2021-01-03 09:08:19.150",
    "recipe_id": 2,
    "recipe_name": "chicken nuggets",
    "steps": [
        {
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "step_number": "chicken"
                }
            ],
            "step_id": 7,
            "step_instructions": "Go to backyard",
            "step_number": 1
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "step_number": "chicken"
                }
            ],
            "step_id": 8,
            "step_instructions": "find a chicken",
            "step_number": 2
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 8,
                    "quantity": 250,
                    "step_number": "nuggets"
                },
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 10,
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "step_number": "spices"
                }
            ],
            "step_id": 9,
            "step_instructions": "take its nuggets",
            "step_number": 3
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 8,
                    "quantity": 250,
                    "step_number": "nuggets"
                },
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 10,
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "step_number": "spices"
                }
            ],
            "step_id": 10,
            "step_instructions": "season nuggets with spices",
            "step_number": 4
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 8,
                    "quantity": 250,
                    "step_number": "nuggets"
                },
                {
                    "ingredient_id": 10,
                    "quantity": 50,
                    "step_number": "spices"
                }
            ],
            "step_id": 10,
            "step_instructions": "season nuggets with spices",
            "step_number": 4
        },
```

I added this piece of code to pretty much push the ingredients into an array and if there is no ingredient name it would return an empty array

```
if(step.ingredient_name && step.ingredient_name !== null){
      ingredients.push({
        ingredient_id: step.ingredient_id,
        step_number: step.ingredient_name,
        quantity: step.step_ingredient_quantity
      })
    }else{
      ingredients = []
    }
```

My question is how can I pretty much reverse the way the results are being printed out...inside the steps array. I can see that it is alphabetically, I want to get it looking the way the example above was shown... Im am using javascript for this and build a DB with knex as well as using SQL for DB....

At the same time if you can help with my code where if its null i don't have the ingredients printed out twice like it did with chicken if you see  that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add to the beginning of the ingredients array, just do:

```
ingredients.unshift(object)
```

You can also reverse an array completely with

```
ingredients.reverse()
```

But if you want to sort the objects by a certain property, look at the JavaScript `sort` method. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort